# Setting values for a drop down list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have defined a drop down list in html as follows. I have appended the values for the dropdown from javascript. The value I am trying to set is "5". But it does not work. Can someone tell me another way?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Util.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Language.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function dropdown(){
document.getElementById("numberlist").appendChild(5);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="dropdown();">
<div id="main3"></div>

<select id = "numberlist"><option>12</option><option>24</option><option>36</option></select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which option you want to set to `5`?

Comment: I want to add it to the options. As a new value.

Comment: follow this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying from the original question. Will this solve your issue?

```
function dropdown(){ 
var drp = document.getElementById("numberlist");
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION"); 
optn.text="3";  
optn.value="3";   
drp.add(optn);
}
```